# Dynamically add objects to an array

Tags: javascript

I want to create a datasource dynamically for my table from a array of objects.

Required datasource value:

```
values = [
    {
        name: "Super Admin"
        cv: 1
        assessment1_title: score/status
        assessment2_title: score/status
        interview1_title: score/status
        interview2_title: score/status
    }
]
```

I have the following array of object:

```
  data = {
    "assessments": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "PHP Laravel Developer",
            "type": "Objective"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Laravel Developer",
            "type": "Objective"
        }
    ],
    "candidates": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "user_id": 1,
            "user_name": "Super Admin",
            "assessments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "score": 5,
                    "duration": 1170,
                    "status": {
                        "id": 22,
                        "name": "completed"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "score": 0,
                    "duration": 0,
                    "status": {
                        "id": 22,
                        "name": "Pending"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where the value of assessment_title will be dynamically generated from `data.assessments.map(({title}) => title)` and the `value` will be one of score and status

```
data.canditates.map(res => res.assessments.map(res2=> {
  if res2.status.id ==22 {
    value = res2.score
  } else {
    value = res2.status.name
  }
})
);
```

I want to make the required datasource value. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if res2.status.id ==22` aren't you getting syntax error here ?

Comment: why should it be syntax error? btw, I wanted to make the logic clear, but I need the conversion

Comment: `data.canditates.map(res => res.assessments.map(....))` will return an array of arrays, if you want a single level array, use `.reduce()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by using `reduce` on candidates and then `forEach` assessments element add title and score/status.

```js
const  data = {"assessments":[{"id":6,"title":"PHP Laravel Developer","type":"Objective"},{"id":7,"title":"Laravel Developer","type":"Objective"}],"candidates":[{"id":11,"user_id":1,"user_name":"Super Admin","assessments":[{"id":1,"score":5,"duration":1170,"status":{"id":22,"name":"completed"}},{"id":2,"score":0,"duration":0,"status":{"id":22,"name":"Pending"}}]}]}

const result = data.candidates.reduce((r, c) => {
  const obj = {}
  obj.cv = c.user_id;
  obj.name = c.user_name;
  c.assessments.forEach((e, i) => {
    const {score, status: {name}} = e;
    const {title} = data.assessments[i];
    obj[title] = e.status.id === 22 ? name : score;
  })
  r.push(obj)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

You could also create a bit more flexible solution that will work in case you have more then two keys in original object.

```js
const data = {"assessments":[{"id":6,"title":"PHP Laravel Developer","type":"Objective"},{"id":7,"title":"Laravel Developer","type":"Objective"}],"interviews":[{"id":1,"title":"Interview 1"},{"id":2,"title":"Interview 2"}],"candidates":[{"id":11,"user_id":1,"user_name":"Super Admin","interviews":[{"id":1,"score":3,"status":{"name":"completed"}},{"id":2,"score":0,"status":{"name":"pending"}}],"assessments":[{"id":1,"score":5,"duration":1170,"status":{"id":22,"name":"completed"}},{"id":2,"score":0,"duration":0,"status":{"id":22,"name":"Pending"}}]}]}

const result = data.candidates.reduce((r, c) => {
  const obj = {}
  obj.cv = c.user_id;
  obj.name = c.user_name;
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
    if(k !== 'candidates') {
      data[k].forEach((e, i) => {
        const {title} = e;
        const {score, status: {name}} = c[k][i];
        obj[title] = `${score}/${name}`
      })
    }
  })
  
  r.push(obj)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be something like below.

```js
data = {
  assessments: [
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "PHP Laravel Developer",
      type: "Objective"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: "Laravel Developer",
      type: "Objective"
    }
  ],
  candidates: [
    {
      id: 11,
      user_id: 1,
      user_name: "Super Admin",
      assessments: [
        {
          id: 6,
          score: 5,
          duration: 1170,
          status: {
            id: 22,
            name: "completed"
          }
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          score: 0,
          duration: 0,
          status: {
            id: 21,
            name: "Pending"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

assessments_map = data.assessments.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const {id,...rest} =  val;
    acc[id] = rest;
    return acc
}, {});

assessments_map;


a = data.candidates.map((candidate) => {
    return {name: candidate.user_name,
        ...candidate.assessments.reduce((acc, assessment) => {
            acc[assessments_map[assessment.id].title] =
              assessment.status.id == 22
                ? assessment.score
                : assessment.status.name;         
            return acc;
        }, {})
    }
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was helpful. but I accepted@nenad answer, as it was concise and short. But otherwise, your answer would be accepted. Thanks again